# How to use react-hook-form with ant design or material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, antd, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use react-hook-form library to validate a form. When I render view using ant design or material UI, it does not work correctly.

```
<Input name="firstName" ref={register({ required: true })} />
  {errors.firstName && 'First name is required'}
```

Some warning happened: `"Missing name at....."`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

React Hook Form (I’m its author) embraces uncontrolled components and native inputs, however it’s hard to avoid working with external controlled components such as React-Select, Ant Design, or Material UI. So I have built a wrapper component to help you integrate easier.

From version 4: [**`Controller`**](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller)
Before version 4: [**`react-hook-form-input`**](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form-input) ([Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-hookforminput-rzu9s))

Okay, you may wonder what’s the point of doing this, and what are you getting out of React Hook Form with controlled components? First, you still benefit from our in-built validation, or a schema validation at your choice. Second, this will improve your app or form performance by isolating your input state update, which means your form root can be drawn with zero re-renders, or even without a controlled component.

On top this, I have also built a wrapper component to make things a bit easier:

```
import React from 'react';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { RHFInput } from 'react-hook-form-input';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, register, setValue, reset } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <RHFInput
        as={<Select options={options} />}
        rules={{ required: true }}
        name="reactSelect"
        register={register}
        setValue={setValue}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          reset({
            reactSelect: '',
          });
        }}
      >
        Reset Form
      </button>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense and that extra component which I have created helps you, too.

Comment: my pleasure, feel free to leave question @github or join our spectrum channel when you encounter other issues. https://spectrum.chat/react-hook-form

Answer (score 23):

For Material-UI you can pass `register` through the TextField component prop `inputRef` (I'm also using Yup for validation schemas)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { object, string } from 'yup';

const Form: React.FC = () => {
  const schema = object().shape({
    username: string().required('Username is required'),
    password: string().required('Password is required'),
  });
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({ validationSchema: schema });
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <TextField
        name="username"
        error={!!errors.username}
        label="Username"
        helperText={errors.username ? errors.username.message : ''}
        type="email"
        inputRef={register}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        name="password"
        error={!!errors.password}
        label="Password"
        inputRef={register}
        helperText={errors.password ? errors.password.message : ''}
        type="password"
        fullWidth
      />

      <Button
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        fullWidth
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, much cleaner than using Controller.

Comment: How to set the default input value with this method?

Comment: @LemuelCastro useForm has optional methods you can use. One of them is defaultValues;  there you can define the object with the values you need, and then those properties will get matched by name and set for the fields when loading the form. For more information you can take a look here: [useForm API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useForm)

Comment: In latest v6 version, you may want to follow the example https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#CustomHookwithResolver .

Answer (score 17):

The latest advice for V4 is to use the built-in `<Controller />` component ([docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller)). You don't need to install the extra dependency of `react-hook-form-input`.

From the README.md of [react-hook-form-input](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form-input):

> This component is now a part of React Hook Form V4, and renamed to Controller with much simpler API.

Example:

```
  <Controller
    as={<TextField />}
    name="firstName"
    control={control}
    defaultValue=""
  />
```

Note that the @Bill, the author of the accepted answer, now also [says](https://spectrum.chat/react-hook-form/help/is-this-stackoverflow-answer-from-bluebill1049-on-controlling-ant-design-up-to-date~2f8eb663-9465-4f6d-9bc6-1588d38b3f1d) that the answer is outdated and to "please use controller instead."

Answer (score 5):

Using the inputRef should be enough to the TextField component and for any default value the react-hook-form ([useForm](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useForm)) provide the defaultValue in case that you want to use some default value or material-ui has the defaultValue in their TextField API

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors, watch } = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });



<TextField
  inputRef={register({ required: true })}
  label="Email Address"
  name="email"
  type="email"
  autoComplete="email"
  onChange={handleUpdate}
  error={errors.email}
  helperText={errors.email && 'email required'}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had 0 issues using the `TextField inputRef` approach that some others have mentioned.

```
<TextField
  inputRef={register}
  id="name"
  name="name"
/>
```

I posted a full working version here: https://seanconnolly.dev/react-hook-form-material-ui