# react-hook-form doesn't work when using material UI button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code without material UI button:

```
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
}
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files)
}

...

<form id="myFile" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input id="file1" type="file" {...register("file1")} onChange={handleChange}/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

This works for me, but when I try to add material UI button instead of input, I get onChange value but when I click submit. I don't get any form data.

```
const {register, handleSubmit} = useForm();

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
}
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.files)
}

...

<form id="myFile" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input id="file1" type="file" {...register("file1")} onChange={handleChange} 
    style={{display:"none"}}/>
    <label htmlFor="file1">
        <Button variant="contained" component="span">
             Choose file
        </Button>
    </label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Is there any solution here?

Answer (score 2):

You are forget to mention the type of the button

for Default material ui button type is

```
type="button"
```

[Check this git Document](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L277)

you should mention

```
type="submit"
```

So do like this

```
<Button type="submit" variant="contained" component="span">
             Choose file
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your submit event is controlled by the whole form element `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>` but this is possible only when the form has a relevant submit button like `<input type="submit"/>` but when you use materail ui, MUI button doesnt distincts submit type even if mentioned.
So the solution is to move your `onSubmit` function at form to down the `onClick`  event of your new MUI button.
The code that works is:

`<Button onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} type="submit" variant="contained" component="span"> Submit </Button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import useForm from 'react-hook-form';
import { object, string } from 'yup';

const Form: React.FC = () => {
  const schema = object().shape({
    username: string().required('username required'),
    password: string().required('password required'),
  });
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({ validationSchema: schema });

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <TextField
        name="username"
        error={!!errors.username}
        label="Username"
        helperText={errors.username ? errors.username.message : ''}
        type="email"
        inputRef={register}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        name="password"
        error={!!errors.password}
        label="Password"
        inputRef={register}
        helperText={errors.password ? errors.password.message : ''}
        type="password"
        fullWidth
      />

      <Button
        color="secondary"
        type="submit"
        variant="contained"
        fullWidth
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

ref: [How to use react-hook-form with ant design or material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833574/how-to-use-react-hook-form-with-ant-design-or-material-ui)